# Does unique app id could change on device?

Tags: ios

I have a coredata DB which store pdf absolute path for files.
I discovered that my pdf could not be loaded, after investigation it is because the path for Documents folder has changed becaue App's unique id has changed.

Was /var/mobile/Applications/FEF0A8B5-6FA3-47DA-98EC-732A3FFA6FD3/Documents/
And is now: /var/mobile/Applications/17525DA9-C2C5-4515-9635-0ECC76BE9131/Documents/

Could this happens?
In what situation?

Thanks a lot.

Thierry

Answer (score 1):

When you delete the app, the next time that value will be different.  You can use:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I didn't delete the app. What about replacing app with an update ?
I only made an update using TestFlight.